# How can I restore file in master branch

Tags: git, branch

I was coding on branch called feature/restful-api, and I want to checkout the files in master branch, so I did
`git checkout master` and changed to master branch.
When I wanted to change back, git told me that

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
        gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
        gradlew
        gradlew.bat
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

So I deleted these files and changed back to feature/restful-api branch.
Now I found that all the configurations has gone. How can I restore these file back?

Comment: a piece of advice, next time when you get stuck in this situation. use `git stash` in the working branch and then checkout master branch, when you move back to that working branch, you can apply the changes with `git stash apply`, I would suggest reading about these commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you've deleted the files without Git ever knowing about them. In that case Git can't help you get them back. I'm assuming they're not in Trash/Recycle Bin either.

If you're using IntelliJ IDEA, try the [Local History](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html) feature. Open the project in IDEA, right-click the root of the project and select **Local History** > **Show History...**

I've recovered a few files this way, can be a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on `feature/restful-api branch` and the file changes weren't committed.

```
git ls-files --deleted
```

will list all the files that were deleted.

```
git checkout -- <file>
```

and then this can be used to restore those deleted files.

Comment: I never committed in master branch so nothing shows up when I use `git ls-files --deleted`.

Comment: no not the master branch, switch to the restful-api branch and then perform these commands